# Deserialized Object throws exception of local class incompatible

Tags: java, object, serialization, deserialization, iostream

I wanna ask a question..So,I have a block of code like this:

```
MyOwnObject deserializedObject = null;
try{
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedObject.getBytes());
    ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    deserializedObject = (MyOwnObject)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

someMapper.insert(deserializedObject);
```

PS: serializedObject is a string which I get from serialization process before,and it's working well I think.

UPDATED:
The code throws an exception:

```
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1360826667802527544, local class serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920
```

And in the stacktrace there's something about the type Integer of some attribute in my object..Pardon my newbieness.. :|

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write code like this. (1) Exceptions should never be just ignored, and (2) code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block should be *inside* that `try` block as well. In this case, `deserializedObject` can only exist if everything in the `try` block succeeded, so using it outside that block is meaningless anyway. Don't write code like this.

Comment: thanks..sorry that i'm still a newbie..thanks for the reminder,now i'll always keep your advice on my mind :)
it throws an exception though,something about the serialVersionUID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it before the try catch:

```
MyOwnObject deserializedObject = null;
```

Inside the try/catch, make sure you remove the declaration, and change it to:

```
deserializedObject = (MyOwnObject)ois.readObject();
```

Comment: I already tried it before,and when i debug it,the deserializedObject is still null and cannot be used for the logic i'm putting in my object method..it works well with the normal object though..

Comment: First, do what I suggested above, and that's the right thing to do any way. Now, it is almost always a bad idea to leave the catch block entirely empty. Do you know whether it actually threw any exception?

Comment: Yes,sorry,it threw an exception:

    local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1360826667802527544, local class serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920